# Where can I find the feature "Save to Ubuntu One"?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I hope anyone remembers that UbuntuOne introduced some years ago a feature which allows to integrate a button into a website to directly load files into the visitors UbuntuOne. U1 had set up a demo at this time where it was possible to have sent some music files to my U1. But I can't remember where this was, and after searching the web for a long time, I almost believe I am hallucinating - and this feature never existed. Is this feature no longer available? Why can't I find information about it on the web anymore. Maybe I just had a dream?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Is [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/251721/hosting-a-website-on-ubuntuone/251758#251758) what you are looking for?

Comment: No. After searching really hard, I found it again. You can read about it [here](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2012/04/12/a-sneak-peek-of-send-to-ubuntu-one/) and [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/send-to-ubuntu-one-button), and demo which allows/allowed you to directly send files to your U1 is [here](http://www.sci-fi-london.com/old-time-radio-0). Now I know, I am not hallucinating. But how can I integrate this feature into my website myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is called "Send to Ubuntu One". You can read more about it here:
http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2012/04/12/a-sneak-peek-of-send-to-ubuntu-one/

Just a preview was made available, and it hasn't been published yet.

Comment: After submitting my comment to update the question I realized that both of us found it again - at the same time. The counter showed that I was 24sec faster, but I'll give the credit to you! :-) Thanks!